# why does document.all.item does not work on localhost?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a very old web app which uses document.all.item to iterate through the dom and 
it is causing runtime errors when i deploy the application in localhost and the error dissapears when i deploy it on server outside my machine. Below os the code where it throws the unknown runtime error. what is the reason or how can i go about resolving it?

```
 with(document.all)

  item('fieldName').innerHTML = "Blah Blah";  // Error is on this line.?

}
```

When i tried to debug in IE. I can access the item but cannot access the innerHTML for some reason. Is it because of IE or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Google Chrome, `HTMLAllCollection` (The result from `document.all`) has no `item` property. I'd suggest looping through them with an `for` loop:

```
var items = document.all;
var length = items.length;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
    //Do something with: items[i];
}
```

The behaviour change might be because of inconsistent implementation of a `item` property on `HTMLAllCollection`s, where IE apparently does implement it, and your server doesn't.

Comment: The question is about the apparent behaviour change when switching host names.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: elaborated a bit.

Comment: It is random. sometimes i see the error and the other times i do not. which is very confusing for me.

Comment: @SumanKumar: That's confusing indeed. But in the cases where your code doesn't work, does my answer work?

Comment: I replaced it with document.getElementById and it works fine. I am not sure why document.all.item would not work. Thank you for the help.